# Understanding OCR options in Adobe Acrobat: "Searchable Image", "Searchable Image (Exact)", and "Editable Text and Images"

Tags: adobe-acrobat, ocr

In Adobe Acrobat (I'm using Pro DC if that matters), there are three options for OCR:

1. "Searchable Image".
2. "Searchable Image (Exact)".
3. "Editable Text and Images".

[image]

What are the differences between these three options?

In particular, what determines the output file size? Right now I've been running both the 1st and 3rd options and it seems that sometimes one is bigger and sometimes the other is bigger (and the differences can be substantial).

What (if any) are the trade-offs between quality, file size, and speed of OCR processing?

Comment: The topic that interests you is towards the end of the guide, under the heading [Recognize text in scanned documents](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/scan-documents-pdf.html).       There is also this forum [page](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1133603)

Answer (score 9):

The Adobe Help article
[Scan a paper document to PDF](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/scan-documents-pdf.html),
section Recognize Text - General Settings dialog box,
defines the scan modes as :

> **Searchable Image**
>
> Ensures that text is searchable and selectable. This option keeps the
>   original image, deskews it as needed, and places an invisible text
>   layer over it. The selection for Downsample Images in this same dialog
>   box determines whether the image is downsampled and to what extent.
>
> **Searchable Image (Exact)**
>
> Ensures that text is searchable and selectable. This option keeps the
>   original image and places an invisible text layer over it. Recommended
>   for cases requiring maximum fidelity to the original image.
>
> **Editable Text & Images**
>
> Synthesizes a new custom font that closely approximates the original,
>   and preserves the page background using a low-resolution copy.
>
> **Downsample To**
>
> Decreases the number of pixels in color, grayscale, and monochrome
>   images after OCR is complete. Choose the degree of downsampling to
>   apply. Higher-numbered options do less downsampling, producing
>   higher-resolution PDFs.

I will analyze the effect of these options on the output file size.

All options keep the image, which is probably a large object.

*Searchable Image* rotates the image, which might change its size making it
larger or smaller, depending on the image re-encoding method used internally
by Adobe

*Downsample To* can reduce the image resolution
and so reduce its size, but the amount of space
gained (or lost) depends on the re-sample method used internally by Adobe.

*Editable Text & Images* synthesizes a new font,
which is then included in the PDF and will add several dozens of K-bytes
to the output size.

All in all, there is no clear method for creating the smallest PDF.
The amount gained (or lost) depends on both the images being OCR'ed
and how efficiently they can be re-compressed by Adobe.

If the aim is to save space,
I would suggest to use *Editable Text & Images*,
but as described in this
[Adobe Acrobat article](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/edit-scanned-pdfs.html),
specify in Settings "Use available system font" which might avoid the
custom font.
You may also delete the images, if the OCR'ed text is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I did a mini test on the three OCR types:

- **Searchable Image (Exact)**
- **Searchable Image**
- **Editable Text and Images**

I had a PDF of 40 pages (20MB) and the results are shown below:

[Table with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Svv.png)

Ignoring the mechanics behind the OCR and what effects it has on the fidelity of the PDF. It looks like **Searchable Image (Exact)** is the fastest OCR, whereas **Editable Text and Images** takes the longest, but significantly reduced the size of the file after OCR.

Hope this will help!